# Connect to MongoDB via python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to connect to mongodb using python and code:

```
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://root:password@mongo:27017/database_sample?authSource=admin")
db = myclient.database_sample
my_collection = db["database"]
```

but I'm getting

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Authentication failed.', 'code': 18, 'codeName': 'AuthenticationFailed'}
```

Comment: Authentication failed? Probably a bad password

Comment: password, host and username are correct...

Comment: check your connection string with mongo shell or mongosh

Comment: In your URI, what is **mongo**? Is that a correctly configured hostname? Is it running on your local system or a remote host? Which version of Python? Which version of **pymongo**? Does your password use special characters? There are many possibilities. Details are required to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. I can suggest you a few things. First be sure you are writing db name correctly. Second check if your password is valid. If not try to change the connection path in MongoClient since this function is client only.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct; Authentication failed means that at least one of your `username`, `password` or `authSource` is incorrect **for the current database**. If you have special characters in your password, that *could* be an issue.

At the command prompt **on the same machine you are running the python code**, run:

```
mongo 'mongodb://root:password@mongo:27017/database_sample?authSource=admin'
```

In most circumstances this will exhibit the same behaviour as connecting via python / pymongo.

Permissions are set at a database level, so it could be your username/password works in certain databases but not others. so at the command prompt again it's also worth trying:

```
mongo 'mongodb://root:password@mongo:27017/admin?authSource=admin'
```

and seeing if that connects or exhibits some different behaviour.